# React native using expo custom icon font issues on IOS

Tags: react-native, expo

I am building an app that needs custom font icons. I made a package using IcomoonApp (https://icomoon.io/app/#/select) and downloaded the package.

Per expo documenation there is a function that can generate fonticons for the app by using [createIconSetFromIcoMoon](https://docs.expo.io/guides/icons/#createiconsetfromicomoon).

This is my code for the generation:

```
import { createIconSetFromIcoMoon } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import icoMoonConfig from './selection.json';
const Icomoon = createIconSetFromIcoMoon(icoMoonConfig, 'Icomoon', 'Icomoon.ttf');

export default Icomoon;
```

Next i added the font ttf file in App.js to Font.loadAsync as follows:

```
  const fetchFonts = () => {
    Font.loadAsync({
      'Roboto': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf'),
      'Roboto_medium': require('native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf'),
      'Icomoon': require('./assets/fonts/Icomoon.ttf')
    })
  }
```

After these steps now i tried to add a sample icon to test it out as follows:

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import Icomoon from '../../assets/fonts/Icomoon'; 

const SearchScreen = () => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Icomoon name="back" size={24} color="black" />;
        </View>
    );
};

export default SearchScreen;
```

When i tried to run it in the expo client on my android everything worked just fine, but when i tried to run it on an Iphone (Iphone SE first gen with IOS 14) i got an error when the app tryed to load the ttf file with Font.loadAsync.

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Unable to download file: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=Icomoon.ttf, NSErrorFailingURLKey=Icomoon.ttf, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(]
```

I tried this on expo on both exopo 38 and 39 bubt the error was the same.
I am using a managed workflow with the following package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/react-native-action-sheet": "^3.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.9.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.1",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "expo": "^39.0.3",
    "expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-facebook": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-font": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-google-app-auth": "^8.1.2",
    "expo-google-sign-in": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "^9.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~8.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "^1.0.4",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.7.2",
    "expo-optimize": "^0.1.51",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "qs": "^6.9.4",
    "qs-stringify": "^1.2.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^6.8.4",
    "react-native": "^0.63.2",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-card-stack-swiper": "^1.2.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-image-pan-zoom": "^2.1.12",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-maps": "0.27.1",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.0.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.1.4",
    "react-native-screens": "~2.10.1",
    "react-native-sectioned-multi-select": "^0.7.7",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^3.2.4",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.5.0",
    "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^5.0.2",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.3.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.8.2",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "validate.js": "^0.13.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.6",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Some help would be much appreciated since im stuck on this for a day now.
Many thanks,
Trix

Comment: Managed to find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I think error is in file App.js where you use Font.loadAsync function. This is asynchronous function so you need to await that call.
Try to make new async function, and then from that function call Font.loadAsync().

```
async function LoadFontAsync(){
    await Font.loadAsync(args)
}
```

and then from useEffectHook call LoadFontAsync function.

```
useEffect(()=>{
    LoadFontAsync()
}, [])
```